# How to separate interface and implementation into different modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Hi everyone i am creating a project in Spring Boot with multi-module maven, what i would like to obtain is to seperate the interface and implementation in two different modules, like this:

1. Module A:

```
   public interface MyTestInterface{
   String testMethod();
}
```

2. Module B :

```
  public class MyTestImpl implements MyTestInterface{
  @Override
  String testMethod(){
    return "foo";
  };

}
```

I can't get this result, could you give me an example of how to get it? Also is it a good thing to do this?
As for the poms at the moment I only have a B versus A addiction in the poms.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.some</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The pom of the project that contains A and B module is some likes this:

```
    <modules>
        <module>A</module>
        <module>B</module>

    </modules>
```

Comment: Check if these articles help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856225/maven-separate-modules-for-interfaces-and-implementation-with-spring https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module-project-java-jpms

Comment: Not help me, i couldn't get what I want, i can't import my interface from module A to B, let me give you an example of how to do it?

Comment: It is possible and good practice to do what you're asking. You should 1) Define interface in module A. 2) Define implementation in module B and hence module B depends on module A. 3) Make Spring module to depend on module A, and on module B with scope runtime. The second will allow you to use module B in the tests, but to let your code compile without packaging module B. However, when your code runs, an implementation of A (B or something else) will have to be provided. If the only implementation of A spring should provide is B, then directly add B as compile dependency.

Comment: I tried but i can't get the result I want, i get cyclic dependency errors when run mvn clean install

Comment: @sras, you should not import classes of B into A then. The dependency should flow one way, not both. Review all cases of using something from B in A, and remove them, use a different approach. Without knowing what you actually do in your code, I can't say anything more concrete here, but you will probably be able to find solutions in this site if you look for them (or ask a new question if you can't find anything).

Answer (score 2):

First let's clarify something here.

Your question has to do with `apache-maven` modules, not with java modules.

So now that we are clear let us focus on the issue that you have.

*From comments:*

> I couldn't get what I want, i can't import my interface from module A
> to B

Yes because what you use is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>test.some</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

which means that you have this dependency in module A. So you try to import `Module B` into `Module A`.

What however your requirement needs is exactly the opposite. You need `Module A` inside `Module B`.

For this you have to go to `.pom` of `Module B` and add the following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>test.some</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and also remove the previous dependency that you have in `.pom` inside `Module A` because if not you will have circular dependency issue.

Comment: The problem is that in module A i import the classes of Module B, but from B i want to import the interfaces of A, so i get a circular dependency, how can i solve the problem? How is it possible that we are not possible to do such a thing?

Comment: @sras in that case you create another new module (common module) that contains the elements that will be used for both modules. Then you have only 1 way dependencies and not circular

Answer (score 0):

### You need a parent maven project with packaging as `POM` and modules under them!

Follow this

1. ***Create a maven project with packaging type as POM (It should look something like this, sorry for formatting issues)***

   `<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> <groupId>com.multimodule</groupId> <artifactId>com.example.multimodule</artifactId> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <packaging>pom</packaging> <modules> <module>interface-module</module> <module>implementation-module</module> </modules>`
2. ***Create an interface-module with packaging JAR with parent pointing to project you created in point 1 (See below)***

   `<parent> <groupId>com.multimodule</groupId> <artifactId>com.example.multimodule</artifactId> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> </parent> <groupId>com.example.interface-module</groupId> <artifactId>interface-module</artifactId> <version>1.0</version> <packaging>jar</packaging>`
3. ***Create an implementation-module with packaging JAR with parent pointing to project you created in point 1 and `dependency` to project created in point 2***

   `<parent> <groupId>com.multimodule</groupId> <artifactId>com.example.multimodule</artifactId> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> </parent> <groupId>com.example.implementation-module</groupId> <artifactId>implementation-module</artifactId> <version>1.0</version> <packaging>jar</packaging> <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>com.example.interface-module</groupId> <artifactId>interface-module</artifactId> <version>1.0</version> </dependency> </dependencies>`

**Likewise for other modules ! I was able to achieve what you asked , let me know if you need a reference, will upload and send GitHub link!**

Comment: However, i always have a problem of circular dependencies, because from B i import the classes of A and from B i want to import the interface of A?